# Parse JSON response on MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am doing a HTTP request on WebAPI, and I am getting response of ID.

The response is: `|10123087-0|||`

I need to save only the first eight digits without the `||` and the `|-0|`. How can this be done?

Comment: can you post the actual response you get and some code please in order for us to be able to help you

Comment: `|10123087-0|||` What **exact** value do you want out of that input?

Comment: i need only 10123087

Comment: is that the FULL http response? no json, no xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use action, that takes a string value as parameter

Example

Your JSON request:

```
{'message' : '|10123087-0|||'}
```

Your action

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string message)
{
     // You can also use regular expressions
     var result = message.Replace("-0|||", "").Replace('|', '');
}
```